# No module named 'ModelWrapper'

Tags: wrapper

I am trying to compare the performance of the activation functions in a deep learning model but the coding below gives error regarding the ModelWrapper. The error is as follows: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ModelWrapper'.
Any idea how I can handle it. Thank you!

```
# Activation functions to try
activations = ['relu', 'leaky_relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh']

# Loop over the activation functions
activation_results = {}


def get_model(act_function):
  if act_function not in ['relu', 'leaky_relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh']:
    raise ValueError('Make sure your activation functions are named correctly!')
  print("Finishing with",act_function,"...")
  return ModelWrapper(act_function)


for act in activations:
  # Get a new model with the current activation
  model = get_model(act)
  # Fit the model and store the history results
  h_callback = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=20, verbose=0)
  activation_results[act] = h_callback
activation_results
```